# An integrable Functions is almost everywhere finite

Tags: real-analysis

An integrable Functions is almost everywhere finite

**Attempt**: Let $X = \{ x : f(x) \, \text{  is infinite}\} $. We must show $m(X) = 0$. Suppose $m(X) > 0 $. then on $X$, we have

$$ \int\limits_X f \, dm > \infty$$

which implies $f$ cannot be integrable: contradiction.

Is this a correct solution? thanks

Comment: Mostly correct. You have to do this for both the positive and the negative part of the function. Also, it should be $\int_X fdm=\infty$, not $\int_X fdm>\infty$.

Comment: Did I understand correctly? We know that $\int f =\int f^{+}-\int f^-$. Since $\int f<\infty$ we get $\int f^+$ and $\int f^-$ are finite. Suppose $m(X)>0$. Then $\int f^{+}\ge \int\limits_X f^+ =\infty$ , contradiction.If it is true could you also explain my last equality?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at $[|f| > n]$; you have $|f| \ge |f|\chi_{[|f| > n]}$ and apply dominated convergence.

Comment: Can you explain to me how the dominated convergence applies? I am having a trouble applying it. I know that the functino $|f| \chi_{|f|>n}$ converges to $|f|\chi_{|f| = \infty}$, but then I am stuck