# If a series of functions is integrable, then is it convergent for almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I get a question when I read Stein's "Real Analysis" on page 70.

If a function is defined by a series of functions, and this series is integrable, then must the series (partial sums) be convergent almost everywhere?

Comment: What do you mean by "integrable"?

Comment: Also must what be convergent? Are you referring to the series partial sums?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: @Gautam Shenoy. Yes, I mean the series partial sums.

Comment: Are you looking for this: "a real function $f$ is integrable then $f$ is finite almost everywhere"? Find  it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552302/an-integrable-functions-is-almost-everywhere-finite).

Comment: @Fermé somme. Thanks. But does "finite" mean it has certain finite value or just be like a bounded random variable?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes, it is exactly what you write, then must g converge for almost everywhere x? Since we can prove g is finite almost everywhere.

Comment: @Curran It means having a certain finite value. In your case if $f = \sum f_n$, then integrability of $f$ implies that $\sum f_n$ is finite a.e., i.e., $\sum f_n$ converges almost everywhere.