# Use Fatou Lemma to show that $f$ takes real values almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, lp-spaces

> Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $L^p$ such that for each positive integer $n$,
>   $
> \| f_{n+1}-f_n\|_{p}
> <\frac 1{2^n} 
> $.
>   Define $f: X \to [0,\infty]$ with
>   $$
> f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty| f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)|.
> $$
>   Use Fatou Lemma to show that $f$ takes real values almost everywhere.

---

**My thoughts:**

We must show the existence of $A$ such that $\mu(A)=0$ and for all $x\in A^C$, $f\in\mathbb R$ using Fatous Lemma which states 
$$
\int_X\liminf_nf_n
\le\liminf_n\int_X f_n.
$$

My idea taking pieces of the completeness proof of $L^p$ is that we have that the series $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\vert f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)\vert$ converges so $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\vert f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)\vert<\infty$ and this holds for all $x\in X$ and then how will I define the set $A$?

I am not using at all Fatou Lemma because I don't know how.

---

[Added later:]

I would also like to understand steps of the proof in [Alex R.'s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3270173/9464) below.

It is shown that

> $$\int_A|f(x)|^pd\mu\leq \liminf_m\int_A|F_m(x)|^p dx\leq\liminf_m\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{2^{pn}}d\mu<\infty.$$

There are a lot of missing steps. I tried to fill.

$\displaystyle\int_A\vert f(x)\vert^pdx
=\int_A|\liminf_mF_m(x)|^pdx=\int_A\liminf_m|F_m(x)|^pdx\le\liminf_m\int_A|F_m(x)|^pdx
=\liminf_m\int|\sum^m_{n=1}|f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)||^pdx
\fbox{=}\liminf_m\sum^m_{n=1}\int_A|f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)|^pdx
=\liminf_m\sum^m_{n=1}||f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)||_p^p\le\liminf_m\sum^m_{n=1}\frac{1}{2^{np}}\fbox=?$

**Question1:** Assuming the equalities and inequalities are correct, Why is the *second* equality, the *boxed* equality and what is equal in the last boxed equality?

It is also shown that

> Taking $A$ to be $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $\int_A|f(x)|^pd\mu<\infty$ which implies $\mu(\{|f|=\infty\})=0$.

**Question2:** Should not have been written as

Take $A$ to be $\mathbb R.$

From all the arguments above (and not only $A=\mathbb R$), it follows that $\int_A|f(x)|^pd\mu<\infty$ which implies $\mu(\{|f|=\infty\})=0$ ??

Seems like as it originally stands, the affirmation depends **only**  on $A=\mathbb R$. But it is independent of taking $A$ as $\mathbb R$. Am I correct?

Comment: You may like to integrate on $X$ since $f_n\in L^p$.

Comment: Which book are you using?

Comment: @Jack ? .You mean like to know where this exercise is from? If yes, then I don't know. This is from a list of exercises that prof posted.

Comment: What is "the proof" you refer to? Could you cite the whole proof of your statement? (It seems that you mean the proof in Alex's answer.)

Comment: @Jack Yes, that is the proof I am referring to: Alex R. proof

Comment: @galleta: It seems that you have changed your question significantly: Originally, you asked a proof for the exercise you posted, but later you had specific concerns regarding one particular answer and you changed your post, which may invalidate another answer, even Alex's one. I think it better to keep those questions under Alex's answer. Or you could make a new post regarding those specific concerns.

Comment: In this exercise, do you have any assumptions on the measure space $X$? If it is arbitrary, then it does not make sense in general to say "take $A$ to be $\mathbb{R}$".

Comment: @Jack  hmm is it not permitted? Well I could see that there is the bounty option that says: _the current answers needs more details_ so I thought that would not be so much problem editing my question again tho this time to ask for details.

Comment: @galleta: that is no a very big deal anyway, just a suggestion `;)`

Comment: @Jack  nop, no assumptions on $X$

Comment: @Jack  "I think it better to keep those questions under Alex's answer." I asked him and he did not reply (It took him 6 long days to reply and my bounty. I though he will never reply)

Comment: @Jack that's correct, no $p$ exponent.

Comment: What is your assumption of $p$? $1\leq p\leq\infty$ or $1\le p<\infty$?

Comment: @Jack I don't know. Probably $p<\infty$. Since it's not specified then wlog $p<\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to directly answer your original question (for $1\le p< \infty$):

> Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $L^p$ such that
>   $$
> \| f_{n+1}-f_n\|_{p}
> <\frac 1{2^n} \quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
> $$
>   and define $f: X \to [0,\infty]$ with
>   $$
> f(x):= \sum_{n=1}^\infty| f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)|.\tag{1}
> $$
>   Use Fatou Lemma to show that $f$ takes real values almost everywhere.

For each positive integer $N$, define  $F_N:X\to[0,\infty]$ with $F_N(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N|f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)|.$ Then for each $x\in X$,
$$
f(x)=\lim_{N\to\infty}F_N(x)
$$ by the definition of $f$, and thus by continuity of the function $z\mapsto z^p$, for each $x\in X$,
$$
|f(x)|^p=\big(\lim_{N\to\infty}F_N(x)\big)^p=\lim_N |F_N(x)|^p.
$$

Now by Fatou lemma, 
$$
\int |f|^p\,d\mu\le \liminf_N \int |F_N|^p.\tag{2}
$$
But by the Minkowski inequality, for each $N$,
$$
\int |F_N|^p=
\|F_N\|_p^p\le (\sum_{n=1}^N\|f_{n+1}-f_n\|_p)^p\le(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{2^{n}})^p
\tag{3}
$$

Taking $\liminf_{N\to\infty}$ in (3) and then applying (2), one gets
$$
\int |f|^p<\infty
$$
and thus $\mu\{x\in X:|f(x)|^p=\infty\}=0$ and hence<sup>1</sup> $\mu\{x\in X:|f(x)|=\infty\}=0$.

---

<sup>1</sup> See, e.g. this standard result: [An integrable Functions is almost everywhere finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/552302/9464)

Comment: Thank you Jack `:)`

Comment: @galleta: You are welcome. For your second "Question" in the post, the answer is simple: since you are talking about general measure space $X$, it does not make sense to say let $A=\mathbb{R}$. The set $X$ could be for instance $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @galleta: the "second inequality" in your first "Question" uses continuity of the function $z\mapsto z^p$.

Comment: Indeed. does not make sense to take $A=\mathbb R$.

Comment: This is also by continuity $|f(x)|^p=\lim_N |F_N(x)|^p,\quad x\in X.$ right. In other answer you said was because of continuity. How exactly?

Comment: @galleta: I don't understand your comment. I mean for each *fixed* $x$, one has by continuity of the power function $z^p$ that $$|\lim_mF_m(x)|^p=(\lim_mF_m(x))^p=\lim_m([F_m(x)]^p).$$ Note that $\liminf_m$ is the same as $\lim_m$ in this particular case and $F_m$ is nonnegative (so that you don't need the absolute value).

Comment: @galleta: I see your confusion. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: where I can I find the proof for continuity of power function $z^p$ implies $(\lim z)^p=\lim z^p$?

Comment: @galleta: that is not what continuity of the function $g(z)=z^p$ ($z>0$) mean here. The continuity implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^p=(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n)^p$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists. The proof is simple: $z^p=e^{p\ln z}$, which is a composition of two continuous functions.

Comment: :) idk I'll think about it, thanks again!

Comment: @galleta: you may be thinking too hard :) That function is differentiable: $(z^p)'=pz^{p-1}$ $(p>1)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95600/discussion-between-galleta-and-jack).

Comment: Jack: I was review again and I have a doubt. You wrote: Combining (2) and (3) and taking →∞ in (3) one has
$∫||^<∞$. When combining (2) and (3) one has $\displaystyle\liminf_N(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{2^n})^p$ which by definition is $\displaystyle\sup\{\inf\{\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{2^n})^p:m\le N\}:N\le 0\}$ and that should be equal to $1$. And then are you using the fact that the limit of the series exists thus $\liminf=\lim=1$ and thus the integral would be finite, right?

Comment: Nevermind, I think goes directly, since $\lim$ exists, then $\liminf=\lim=1.$ Sorry

Comment: @g.a.l.l.e.t.a: Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F_m(x)=\sum_{i=1}^m|f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)|$. Since $F_m(x)$ is increasing for each $x$, its limit in $m$ necessarily exists in the extended reals. So $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}F_m(x)=\liminf_{m\rightarrow\infty}F_m(x)=f(x)$

Then by Fatou:

$$\int_A|f(x)|^pd\mu\leq \liminf_m\int_A|F_m(x)|^p dx\leq\liminf_m\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{2^{pn}}d\mu<\infty.$$

Taking $A$ to be $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $\int_A|f(x)|^pd\mu<\infty$ which implies $\mu(\{|f|=\infty\})=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: I have a question, why Taking  to be ℝ, it follows that $∫_|()|^<∞$

Comment: @galleta: Because we showed the integral is bounded for all $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since $\Vert f_{n+1}-f_n\Vert_p<\frac 1{2^n}$, if $g_k(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^k\vert f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)\vert$ , then Minkowski's inequality implies that $\|g_k\|_p\le 1.$ And now an application of Fatou to $(g^p_k)$  shows that  $\|f\|_p\le 1$, for the $f$ as in your question, and this implies that $f(x)<\infty$ almost everywhere.

Comment: You're using "$f_n$" for two different things...

Comment: I think the argument is ok now.

Comment: No, the notation is still very confused. $\sum_{k=1}^k$ makes very little sense, and you're using $f_k$ to mean rwo different things. (The problem with the first version  wasn't too many $n$'s,  it was too many $f$'s...) The _argument_ will be fine if you ever get the notation straight.

Comment: Except for the typo (that I fixed), I do not see where my mistake is. Can you help? Or I guess I could check Royden/Rudin, etc. I am sure this is done in those texts.

Comment: The notation  $f_k(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^k\vert f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)\vert$ now makes sense, but the equality is simply wrong! Look. For $n=2$ you're saying $f_2=|f_2-f_1|+|f_3-f_2|$. Why would that be so? Pick a different letter for that partial sum.

Comment: Ugh...!! Thanks!

Comment: Yippee.........