# Proving an integrable function is finite almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ be lebesgue integrable. Prove that $f$ is finite almost everywhere.

Attempt: Define \begin{equation}A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:f(x)=\infty\}.\end{equation}

We need only prove that $\lambda_n(A)=0$, where $\lambda_n$ denotes Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume the contrary, that $\lambda_n(A)>0$. Since $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, we have the following bound:

\begin{equation}
\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}fd\lambda_n\right|<\infty.
\end{equation}

Moreover, if $f$ is integrable we also have

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f|d\lambda_n<\infty.
\end{equation}

But if $\lambda_n(A)>0$ then this inequality is not satisfied, which is a contradiction. So our result follows.

I am not sure how to justify rigorously the last step here - any help would be great. Is the remainder of the argument correct?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/552302/42969

Comment: For the last step, separate your integral over $R$ in integral over $A$ and the complementary of $A$. Since $A$ has positive lebesgue measure, the result follows.